# Need Help Sending MySQL Table Info in Email

Tags: php, mysql, database, html-email

I am trying to email values from a MySQL database to a user when prompted.  I cannot seem to pass the information off to the body of the email message with the correct values.  Here is a code sample:

```
mysql_connect ("host","name","pass")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("db_name");

$sql = mysql_query("select * from table_name where id = '$id'");
//$id is previously defined as the users id 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$title = $row["title"];
}

$email = 'user@email.com'
$subject = "Titles";
$body = "Title: " . $title;

if (mail($email, $subject, $body)) {
echo("<p>successfully sent. "</p>");
} else {
echo("<p>delivery failed...</p>");
}
```

I have tried running an array in the while loop to get the title values to display, but again I cannot seem to get these values to carry over to the email message.

This is assuming that each user has multiple titles being sent to them.  Ideally, the final email message would be something like:

```
Title: Title1
Title: Title2
Title: Title3
Title: Title4
Title: Title5
```

and continue on for however many titles are in the array.  Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql_connect ("host","name","pass")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("db_name");

$body = '';  // start with empty string

$sql = mysql_query("select * from table_name where id = '$id'");
//$id is previously defined as the users id 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
     $body .= 'Title: ' . $row['title'] . "\n";
}

$email = 'user@email.com'
$subject = "Titles";
// removed $body= ... 

if (mail($email, $subject, $body)) {
echo("<p>successfully sent. "</p>");
} else {
echo("<p>delivery failed...</p>");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing first: This code is very ripe for a sql injection attack. Fix it!
http://www.learnphponline.com/security/sql-injection-prevention-mysql-php

$title variable is inside while loop, it's not available out-side of the scope. pull it outside.

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/102020-variable-scope-within-while-loop/

Comment: Thank you for your comments, but I still am faced with the issue of how to get the array data to read as I mentioned.  Is there some sort of print and search option to view array results?

Answer (score 0):

you have a concatenation problem,

```
// use this code inside the while   
$title .= 'Title: ' . $row["title"] . '<br>';   // notice the dot before the equal

//and this line in replace of   $body = "Title: " . $title;
$body = $title;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd propose to store title's in an **array** like this:

```
$title = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

  // [] adds a new element at the end of an array
  $titles[] = $row["title"];

}
```

Then, to prepare the body, try this:

```
$body = 'You've gained these titles: ';    

foreach( $titles as $title ) {

      // keep all titles in separate lines of the email body
      $body .= "\nTitle: " . $title;

}
```